# Validate HTML document which should not contain tags with same id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My form has a `textarea` and a submit button. The textarea is used to input HTML code and I want to use JavaScript (JQuery) to validate the input with regex. If multiple html tags have the same `id` value, the entire source is printed on the page with the offending tags marked red.

Comment: *"...validates input with regex..."* That's a red flag right there. You cannot reliably parse/validate HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: You can downvote but in fact, its an interresting question just badly formulated

Comment: Convert the string to a dom fragment and loop through every node looking for id's. when you find an id, search for similar id's within the fragment using `$("[id=" + theid + "]").length`. Note however that invalid html nesting will result in varying fragments per browser.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? I think it’s a valid question, especially if you think around the regexp suggestion.

Comment: I really would like to see that code

Comment: it is badly formulated because i know english bad sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this snippet:

[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shNuK/)

```
var isValid = true;
$('[id]').each(function() {
    if ($('[id="'+this.id+'"]').length > 1) {
        isValid = false;
        return false;
    }
});

alert(isValid);​
```